# flutter Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I am trying to run my `flutter` app via vs code and use the iOS emulator.

I run this command:

```
flutter run --verbose
```

after 20 minutes, it gives me this error:

```
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

I am not sure why this is happening? Any ideas?

Comment: Sadly, this can have lots of possible causes. What does "flutter doctor -v" say? Also, when you run "flutter run --verbose", there should be a lot more detail provided then just "failed with nonzero exit code", it might just be hard to find. If you cant find it yourself, you could try to copy it to pastebin and link to there so that we can assist you

Comment: @JoRa I actually got it to run, finally! once I ran flutter test, it showed me what's wrong without waiting the 20 minutes, I was able to fix it and it worked. Problem is, it's not my code so I didn't know any better lol! But thanks for your comment nonetheless